# Creating a user/entity using Janrain Capture RESTful API

Tags: janrain

Is it possible to create a user/entity using Janrain Capture without using the built in registration widgets, but using the RESTful API?

http://developers.janrain.com/documentation/capture/api-use-and-error-codes/

I am hoping to ask a user a number of questions through a number of steps and then at the end register them with this data, and not to use the built in Widgets.

Also I am hoping to write apps on different devices (e.g. TV's) who also can register users but may not run javascript, and was hoping the backend could use REST to create the user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the method to check if a users login/pwd are correct.  You can pass the username and password as attributes, and not use the id.

http://developers.janrain.com/documentation/api/entity/

You can then have to maintain your own cookie states for being logged in (storing the tokens in a secure cookie would be one option)

And this is the registration method

http://developers.janrain.com/documentation/api/entity-create/